# python list that matches everything

Tags: python, filtering, list-comprehension

I probably didn't ask correctly: I would like a list value that can match any list: the "inverse" of `(None,)`
but even with `(None,)` it will match item as None (which I don't want)

The point is I have a function working with: `[x for x in my_list if x[field] not in filter_list]`

and I would like to filter everything or nothing without making tests like:
`if filter_list==(None,): return []` and `if filter_list==('*',): return my_list`

PS: I wanted to simplify my question leading to some errors (`list` identifier) or stupid thing `[x for x in x]` ;)

---

Hi,

I need to do some filtering with list comprehension in python.

if I do something like that:

```
[x for x in list if x in (None,)]
```

I get rid of all values, which is fine

but I would like to have the same thing to match everything

I can do something like:

```
[x for x in list if x not in (None,)]
```

but it won't be homogeneous with the rest

I tried some things but for example `(True,)` matches only  `1`

Note than the values to filter are numeric, but if you have something generic (like `(None,)` to match nothing), it would be great

Thanks
Louis

Comment: `list` is a reserved word, you shouldn't use it as an identifier.

Comment: indeed: this was for demonstration purpose only:I removed it anyway

Comment: may be you could post an example of what you want? say you have `my_list = [1, 2, None, 4]` and `filter_list` = [2]` what should be the output. do add inputs of your own

Comment: @Louis: Please delete the old question; it makes no sense.  It's actually better to delete this question and start again with a brand new question.

Comment: Note that `(None,)` is not exactly a match-nothing: it does math `None`.  What you want to match nothing is `()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__contains__` is the magic method that checks if something is in a sequence:

```
class everything(object):
    def __contains__(self, _):
        return True           

for x in (1,2,3):
    print x in everything()
```

Answer (score 4):

The better syntax would be:

```
[x for x in lst if x is None]
[x for x in lst if x is not None]
```

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by

> I would like to have the same thing to match everything

Just do

```
[x for x in list]
```

and every item in `list` is matched.

Answer (score 3):

You could change your program to accept a filter object, instead of a list.

The abstract base filter would have a `matches` method, that returns true if x *matches".

Your general case filters would be constructed with a list argument, and would filter on membership of the list - the `matches` function would search the list and return `true` if the argument was in the list.

You could also have two special subclasses of the filter object : none and all.

These would have special match functions which either always return `true` (all) or `false` (none).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an `if`, you can just say

```
[x for x in list]
```

Comment: How can you justify this:
>>> l = [None, 1, 3]
>>> [x for x in l]
[None, 1, 3]

Comment: @aatifh: that's not python syntax

Comment: the `if` was because I filter on a field: ti's now correct in question

Answer (score 0):

> but I would like to have the same
>   thing to match everything

To match everything, you don't need if statement

```
[x for x in list1]
```

or If you really like to do

```
[x for x in list1 if x in [x]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your revised question: the list that "matches" all possible values is effectively of infinite length. So you can't do what you want to do without an if test. I suggest that your arg should be either a list or one of two values representing the "all" and "none" cases:

```
FILTER_NONE = object() # or []
FILTER_ALL = object()

def filter_func(alist, filter_list):
    if filter_list is FILTER_ALL:
        return []
    elif filter_list is FILTER_NONE:
        return alist
        # or maybe alist[:] # copy the list
    return [x for x in alist if x not in filter_list]
```

If filter_list is large, you may wish the replace the last line by:

```
    filter_set = set(filter_list)
    return [x for x in alist if x not in filter_set]
```

Alternatively, don't bother; just document that filter_list (renamed as filter_collection) can be anything that supports  `__contains__()` and remind readers that sets will be faster than lists.